# how does the below code output 3? (how does the below code read?)

Tags: c++11, if-statement, int, signed

The specific part I do not understand is how the `-a` in the if statement changes -3 to 3. Can someone explain how the `-a` changes `a = -3` to `a = 3`?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

signed a = -3;

if (a < 0){ std::cout << -a << std::endl; }
else { std::cout << a << std::endl; }

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"how does the below code == 2?"_ What are you asking ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an example of [unary negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation#C_family_of_languages), when `a=-3` (which is less than `0`, the code then enters the `if` block) then `-a` is `-(-3)` which is `3`.

Answer (score 0):

This code won't change the value of 'a' at all. It will remain 3 (a=3) even after execution of if statement. You can check this by adding

```
 std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

in your if statement. The system just prints the value of -1*a i.e. (-a)